# Finding matrix tranformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $M_2(\mathbb {F})$ denote the set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices over the field $\mathbb {F}$. Observe that $M_2(\mathbb {F})$ becomes a vector space if addition and scalar multiplication are defined by 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1  &  x_2      \\ 
    x_3  &  x_4      
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_1  &  y_2      \\ 
    y_3  &  y_4      
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1+y_1  &  x_2+y_2      \\ 
    x_3+y_3  &  x_4+y_4      
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
\lambda * \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1  &  x_2      \\ 
    x_3  &  x_4      
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda*x_1  &  \lambda*x_2      \\ 
    \lambda*x_3  &  \lambda*x_4      
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let $\mathcal{E} = \{E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4\}$ where $E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1  &  0      \\ 
    0  &  0      
\end{bmatrix}$, $E_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0  &  1      \\ 
    0  &  0      
\end{bmatrix}$, $E_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0  &  0      \\ 
    1  &  0      
\end{bmatrix}$, $E_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0  &  0      \\ 
    0  &  1      
\end{bmatrix}$, and let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1  &  0      \\ 
    -1  &  1      
\end{bmatrix}$ and let $S: M_2(\mathbb {F})\rightarrow M_2(\mathbb {F})$ be the linear mapping $S(X) = AX - XA$. Find $M(S) _\mathcal{E} ^ {\mathcal{E}} $.

My attemp to solve this was:

I first tried to investigate where the given mapping sends $\mathcal{E}$:

$S(E_1) = \begin{bmatrix}
    0  &  0      \\ 
    -1  &  0      
\end{bmatrix} = -E_3$

$S(E_2) = \begin{bmatrix}
    1  &  0      \\ 
    0  &  -1      
\end{bmatrix} = E_1-E_4$

$S(E_3) = \begin{bmatrix}
    0  &  0      \\ 
    0  &  0      
\end{bmatrix} = E_n - E_n$ where $1 \leq n \leq 4$

$S(E_4) = \begin{bmatrix}
    0  &  0      \\ 
    1  &  0      
\end{bmatrix} = E_3$

but then I am not sure as to how present $M(S) _\mathcal{E} ^ {\mathcal{E}} $. I initially thought it would be:
$M(S) _\mathcal{E} ^ {\mathcal{E}} 
= $\begin{bmatrix}
    0  &  1& 0 & 0      \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    -1  &  0 & 0 & 1 \\
     0 & -1 & 0 & 0      
\end{bmatrix} (i.e. I wrote out coefficients in front of $E_n$ in columns as this is how we have been taught)

but then this cannot be true since as fas as I understand $M(S) _\mathcal{E} ^ {\mathcal{E}} $ has to be a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are correct until you say $M(S)$ is a $2x2$ matrix. It is a $4x4$ matrix as it represents a linear map from a $4$-dimensional vector space to itself.

Comment: But should not we be able to obtain, for example $S(E_1)$ by finding the product of $M(S)$ and $E_1$? If yes, then how can we multiply 4x4 matrix by 2x2?

Comment: Given the basis $(E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4)$, $E_1$ corresponds to the vector $(1,0,0,0)^T$. Applying $M(S)$ gives the vector $(0,0,-1,0)^T$ which corresponds to $-E_3$ under the basis $(E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4)$.

Comment: Oh right, thank you! However, why are we not representing $E_1$ as a column vector? When thinking about it I actually did the following: $M(S)*E_1$ where I represented $E_1$ as a column vector $(1,0,0,0)$. But then it did not works as I got all 0s when multiplying the matrices. Could you please explain why in multiplication we first write the vector and not the transformation?